# Tsql query need to find duplicates and join tables to determine which ones to delete

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query that works and returns correct duplicate data.

```
select [serverName], ActiveYN, count(servername)
from dbo.FarmStats_Server
group by [serverName], ActiveYN 
having (count(servername) > 1)
```

returns 260 rows.

What I need to do is a bit more complicated.

```
 SELECT 
     dbo.FarmStats_Farm.FarmName, 
     dbo.FarmStats_Server.ServerName,
     dbo.FarmStats_Server.obsDT, dbo.FarmStats_Server.ActiveYN
 FROM 
     dbo.FarmStats_Farm 
 INNER JOIN
     dbo.FarmStats_Server ON dbo.FarmStats_Farm.FarmID = dbo.FarmStats_Server.FarmIDFK
 GROUP BY 
     dbo.FarmStats_Farm.FarmName, dbo.FarmStats_Server.ServerName, dbo.FarmStats_Server.obsDT, dbo.FarmStats_Server.ActiveYN
 HAVING   
     (COUNT(dbo.FarmStats_Server.ServerName) > 1)
```

This query returns no results. I am missing something fundamentally.

End goal will be to delete one of the duplicates.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is returned when you run the query without the group by section? If you get results, can you see if there are any duplicates in that. Your INNER JOIN may be filtering out data you don't expect it to.

Comment: @Jay Do you want to only delete one duplicate or only retain a single record? So if you have 3 records with the same [serverName] and [ActiveYN] do you want two to remain or only one?

Comment: Eric you are correct.  the goal here is to remove duplicate records, based on age.  the newest will be set to active the rest will need to be removed from the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this in subquery as below:

```
SELECT
    dbo.FarmStats_Farm.FarmName,
    dbo.FarmStats_Server.ServerName,
    dbo.FarmStats_Server.obsDT,
    dbo.FarmStats_Server.ActiveYN
FROM dbo.FarmStats_Farm
INNER JOIN dbo.FarmStats_Server fs
    ON dbo.FarmStats_Farm.FarmID =
    dbo.FarmStats_Server.FarmIDFK
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT
    [serverName],
    ActiveYN
FROM dbo.FarmStats_Server
WHERE servername = fs.servername
AND activeyn = fs.activeyn
GROUP BY    [serverName],
            ActiveYN
HAVING (COUNT(servername) > 1))
```

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to accomplish.  the Sub Query does not limit the result to just duplicates.  It presents all records in table.